# Distinct duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, distinct-values

I am still getting duplicates results and i'm using distinct.

```
public function aa(Request $request){

    $term = $request->get('term');

    $queries = Profile::distinct('cityandstate')->where('cityandstate', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')->pluck('cityandstate');

    foreach ($queries as $query)
    {
        $results[] = ['value' => $query->cityandstate ];
    }       

    return response()->json($results);
}
```

Comment: distinct .. and group by  ????

Comment: I did something wrong?

Comment: show your table structure with some data

Answer (score 0):

The following should work with laravel 5.2 or higher:

```
$results = Profile::distinct('cityandstate')->where('cityandstate', 'like', '%' . $term . '%')->pluck('cityandstate');
return response()->json($results);
```

Comment: Its not working.No results are being shown. I'll show you what I put. I edited the code

Comment: @BeBeautiful22 you added the foreach again which is not necessary with the pluck method. It replaces that behaviour

Comment: Thanks for replying I thought you forgot. I just tried it. Its almost working but when I search for miami,fl there is no duplicate which is great, but when I search for Atlanta,Ga it gives me a duplicate  for that. Oh boy we are almost there

Comment: @BeBeautiful22 is everything in the table lowercased or uppercased? In other words, can there be duplicates based on casing? If so you should filter that out first.